# What are the axioms of modern mathematics?

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory, foundations

I took the claim that set theory is the foundation of mathematics seriously and thought ZFC is the axiom of mathematics.

However, I became confused after learning about category theory. The category of sets cannot be constructed in ZFC. It seems to me that an alternative foundation to ZFC is needed.

On what axiomatic system is modern mathematics based?

Comment: Why go that far? ZFC can't construct a model of ZFC. And as per Gödel's restrictions, there is no effective list of "the axioms" for modern mathematics. What we normally do is interpret things in ZFC + large cardinal axioms, where the latter also serve as a good measure of consistency strength.

Comment: Foundational issues sort of like asking if you should define a collection of trees as forest or a forest as a collection of trees.

Comment: Different theories have different sets of axioms.

Comment: This is a very high level question. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but what I recall hearing after having asked a similar question some time ago, goes like this: The Category of Set is in some sense, the "primordial category", in which all other 1-Categories can be described (excluding things like Topoi). ZFC then forms the axioms for this category, in which *most* of mathematics can be done. However, higher mathematics like homotopy theory, requires higher categories like 2-Categories (categories of categories), etc, which are in some sense, transcendental to set theory.

Comment: @Graviton: Yes, but not quite right. This is why we have large cardinal axioms. We can use universes, whose existence follows from large cardinals. One can argue that it is not satisfying, since we don't have a "real 2-Category of all sets". But at the same time, why do we really need one? And if we really do, we can have universes that are elementary in "the full universe", so they reflect any and all things. So, no, these things are transcendental to ZFC, but so what? Literally 95% of set theory is done in a way that is transcendental to ZFC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know almost nothing but the statement “$95\%$ of set theory is done in a way that is transcendental to ZFC” is troubling me. Do you mean, $95\%$ of “set theory” as in the *interesting* set theory which is more modern, is researched and developed, i.e. is advanced, or do you also refer to the set theory which is used by mathematicians and mathematics students whose work/interests is not closely involved with set theory, i.e. the basic manipulations any undergrad is forced to use and know?

Comment: @FShrike: Yes, of course. Venn diagrams require large cardinals. Everyone knows that... :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I will assume you meant to refer to the set theory which is more advanced, then ; ) Sorry to bother you, but reading your comments makes me think that even statements like: "most category theory can be safely done with NBG set theory" are also wrong. Is that another naive but commonly held view?